# Factorise this polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Could I get some help factorising this equation. I can't seem to find the factor. Any help or hints.

$$P(x) = x^3 + 4 x^2 - 3x - 18$$

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use a mathematical software to get an insight? :-)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Is the [rational root  theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) in your tool set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try x = 2 we see that P(2) = 0 so x - 2 is a factor of P(x). And using synthetic division to get the other factors.

Comment: Cheers for that

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try regrouping and then factoring.

$ (x^3 + 3x^2) + (x^2 - 3x - 18) $

Now factor the 2 groups for a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is a homework problem, If so the factors will have only integers (or you can try these first)

If the factor has only integers, it must be of the form
$$(x-a)$$ where $a$ divides 18, So choices of $a$ are $\pm 1$, $\pm 2$, $\pm 3$, $\pm 6$, $\pm 9$, $\pm 18$. 
If $(x-a)$ is a factor then (Pa) = 0$. So you can quickly check these to get

$$\left(x-2\right)\,\left(x+3\right)^2$$

Comment: Care to further explain.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x =2$ is a root of $P(x) = x^3 + 4x^2 - 3x - 18$, so all we need to do next is divide $P(x)$ by $x - 2$; the quotient, after synthetic division, is $x^2 + 6x + 9 = (x  + 3)^2$, so $P(x) = (x - 2)(x + 3)^2$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you. I can't vote up sorry.

Comment: @ Orbit:  if you like my (or anyone's) work you can "accept", the green checkmark.  In any event, glad to help out and thanks for the kind words.